# Articles for words that function as both a verb or a noun

Tags: articles

Do I need to include an article (if yes, which one) before words that can be either a verb or a noun?

For example, consider "install."

Do I say "After inserting the disk, you need to run install" or "[...], you need to run the install"?

Comment: In the case you've provided, isn't `install` short for `the installation software`?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think *install* is widely accepted as a noun. It should be

> After inserting the disk, you need to run the installer

However, if there is a file named "install" which must be run, then

> After inserting the disk, you need to run install[.ext]

is fine.

Comment: When a name is involved, it is normal to show this by the use of quotes: **Press** '**Go**'. (or Press the '**Go**' button.) However, computers have hijacked punctuation for their own purposes, so it makes sense to defer to their dictates if you want the thing to work.

Comment: Anything can be used as a noun. Because anything can be a name. It doesn't matter how common it is. Strange names are very uncommon. If what one calls it is _the `install` program_, either _the `install`_ or just _`install`_ is perfectly fine. Or you could call your script `George`, and say _Just run `George`_; anything that's understood is OK. And there are no consistent rules for article usage; only several hundred special rules for individual idiomatic uses.

Comment: @JohnLawler That's true but I suspect the root of the OP's confusion might be that "install" is one of those special cases that is often used incorrectly, outside of the "program named 'install'" situation you've described. In computing, "install" is very often inappropriately used as a short form of the noun "installation", for reasons I don't understand. An English learner exposed to such examples could certainly become legitimately confused. The fact that programs literally named "install" exist complicates it even further, but isn't the sole explanation for this particular word.

Comment: @JasonC [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/install) disagrees with you when you claim ' "install" is one of those special cases that is often used incorrectly ...'.

Comment: There is no "correct" for computing language. 60 years ago there were no computers, so there was no computing language at all. Everything since has been made up on the spot out of [metaphors and duck tape](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/April05Eye.pdf), and reification **always** levels irregular morphology. Look at _New England/*English boiled dinner_, or the _Toronto Maple Leafs/*Leaves_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No it doesn't. It clearly states that "install" as a shortened form of "installation" is both "informal" and "jargon", which is what I said (or at least what I meant). Do you disagree that an English learner's exposure to computing jargon could cause confusion about formal word forms?

Comment: @JohnLawler I do not claim there is "correct" for computing language. I claim there is "correct" for formal language, and that exposure to computing language can easily lead to confusion about formal language, and that the possibility of "install" being a name is not the *sole* explanation for such confusion (but it is one contributing factor, which I wholly agree with you on). Do you disagree?

Comment: I also claim that, for these reasons, "install" is a poor example for the general question about using articles in front of nouns vs. verbs, which I presume is regarding formal language, not computing jargon.

Answer (score 1):

In general you would use articles before common nouns and not before verbs or names.

You can "install" something. You cannot "the install" something.

The choice of "install" as an example for your question is not the best due to its common use in computing jargon, which is potentially contributing to your confusion of the word form. [There is no formal noun "install"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/install). In the OED the only entries for "install" as a noun are exclusively from the writings of G. M. Hopkins circa 1880:

> - 1871   G. M. Hopkins *Jrnls. & Papers* (1959) 207   These are not ribs; they are a ‘wracking’ install made of these two realities—the frets,..and the whiter field of sky shewing between.
> - 1874   G. M. Hopkins *Jrnls. & Papers* (1959) 244   True bold realism but quite a casual install of woodland.
> - 1874   G. M. Hopkins *Jrnls. & Papers* (1959) 245   Happy use of openings, accidental installs, people's feet, hands etc seen through.
> - c1883   G. M. Hopkins *Serm. & Devotional Writings* (1959) ii. iii. 146   For accidental being, such as that of the broken fragments of things or things purely artificial or chance ‘installs’, has no true and intrinsic oneness or true self.

However, "install" is often used as a noun in computing circles as a colloquial shortening of "installation" (e.g. "I am working with a fresh Windows install" or "After the install is complete, ..."), or "installer". Correct formal usage would be e.g. "After the installation is complete, ...".

"You need to run install" would only make sense if there was a program named "install" that you had to run, where "install" is a name.

"You need to run *the* install" would only make sense if "install" were used in the jargon sense as a shortened form of "installer". The article is used as "install" is a common noun in this context, not a verb.

"After you complete *the* install" would only make sense if "install" were used in the jargon sense as a shortened form of "installation". The article is used as "install" is a common noun in this context, not a verb.

Even in the casual forms of your example, articles follow the usual rules; if the word is being used as a common noun you would use an article, if it is being used as a verb, or a name, you would not. It is inconsequential that the noun and verb are the same spelling.

Comment: Wiktionary states that the noun 'install' exists. Language moves on.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Wiktionary states that the noun "install" exists as as a shortened form of "installation" or "installer", and that this usage is "informal" and "jargon", which is precisely what I said here. Still, I have edited to clarify any ambiguity for you.

Comment: Like 'phone' exists as a shortened form of 'telephone'. Wiktionary actually says that this 'Usage originated as a truncated form of the word installation.' Here is an [article](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3dzk1a7gOnAC&pg=PA204&lpg=PA204&dq=install+noun+used+as&source=bl&ots=K2T2GFz2aU&sig=OmBg9k5yiLlwGKOUE-BJRrTQp1k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ygfHU4qRN-Sw0QXgwIC4BA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=install%20noun%20used%20as&f=false) clearly endorsing the use of 'install' as a noun. I'm sure it must be included in OED as such. (Incidentally, an informal register does not imply incorrectness.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, not like "phone" exists as a shortened form of "telephone". Also, your stated Wiktionary definition is exactly what I wrote. Also, the exclusive usage of "install" as a noun in the OED is in G.M. Hopkins' writings circa 1880. Also, the question is not about "install", "install" is a poor example of the generic question of articles in front of verbs / nouns. Also, none of this is in contradiction with anything written in this answer, and so I'm not sure what you are stating.

Comment: I can imagine an earlier Jason saying "No, 'phone' is not a noun. It's only a truncation (which isn't a noun) used in technological registers and labelled 'informal' in Johnson. And only I can decide on what valid sources for acceptable words are. And you shouldn't comment on my claim 'there is no noun "phone" ' because the question was about all sorts of things." I've checked in the Microsoft Encarta College Dictionary [2001], where the noun usage of 'install' is given without any caveats. 'Install' is a noun.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You need to clarify what you are arguing here and what in this answer you find disagreeable. What you are saying is interesting but I cannot give you an interesting response in return without knowing how it relates to the question, the example, or my answer, and I am genuinely confused regarding your intentions at this point.

Comment: You say baldly 'there is no noun 'install'. The references I've cited and other online sources clearly show that this is a claim that not everyone agrees with. And your stance makes your answer unsound. 'After the install' has 5.4 million hits on Google.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There; do you find the edit clearer?

Comment: Yes, but Encarta doesn't restrict the usage to 'informal'. Moving on to the use of the article, John Lawler's comment above best covers this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes some words can be both nouns and verbs. This is quite common in English, where it's caused by zero-derivation. An example is the the verb *to comb* and the noun *a comb*. I believe that no one knows which was the original word and which one came second!

But it appears that this has confused you about how words work in sentences. In a sentence a word cannot be both a noun and a verb! The construction of the sentence will provide the context for you to determine whether or not the word is a noun or a verb. *Comb* can either be a noun or a verb, but it can't be both *at the same time*.

When *comb* is a verb it is completely ungrammatical to put an article before it.

When *comb* is a noun you will usually put an article before it, but not always, such as in the sentence 'Combs are easy to lose.'

For the example you provide, I think the most natural option would be to treat *Install* as a proper noun. So use a capital letter, no article, and perhaps even with quotes:

> After inserting the disk run "Install".

Answer (score -1):

Generally speaking, an article is used to indicate the noun directly following it when that noun represents a specific thing, or specifically understood between the two people speaking.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question that was asked.

Comment: It could answer the question asked if you edit it to explain what should happen when the "noun" is rather abstract, as in the example given in the question.